# NetBeans Java to JavaEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have downloaded the Netbeans version of Java (and not JavaEE). Now I need to create a web application using the IDE. Can you please confirm the website to download the plugin and get the JavaEE features in the IDE.

PS: I am looking for URL where I can download the .nbm file because proxy settings may not allow automatic updates.

Comment: why don't you download the full version instead?

Comment: Netbeans: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/70/ has amazing support for building web apps in the IDE.  You don't necessarily need plugins for it.  Create a new web app using Netbeans following this guide: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html

Comment: is it that bad question to have -1? I was trying to understand the plugin features of eclipse and netbeans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website that holds the numerous plugins that implement the Java EE features of NetBeans 7 is here: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/final/distribution/modules/enterprise/

You may need to get some other plugins from http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/final/distribution/modules/websvccommon/, too.

I would encourage you to ask questions about the proxy issues that you are running into with the Update Center.  Doing the update manually will be a frustrating experience.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the plugin manager

```
Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins
```

If you're having proxy issues then

```
Tools -> General -> Proxy Settings
```

and set your proxy settings.

If you do fin the URL for the nbms you can  either use the plugin manager mentioned above, or use the *update folder* as mentioned in [Geertjans' blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/update_download).

Answer (score 0):

My Netbeans is the version from the Ubuntu 12.04 Software Center repository (7.0). I solved this by checking the options "Certified Plugins","Netbeans Distribution"  and "Plugins Portal", which, by default, were unchecked for active. You can find this on

Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins

In the "Settings" (last) tab.

By making this, reload the "Avaible Plugins" (that was empty for me) and, after some seconds, lots of categories will appear. Look for Java Web and EE and install them (I found only the Java Web plugin).